# Copying to PostgreSQL database from a CSV on a server

Tags: ruby, database, postgresql, csv, engineyard

I am trying to update a PostgreSQL database with a CSV file that I am downloading to the server. I have tried for many hours and it works perfectly locally but cannot get it to work on the server. Here is my command:

```
path = "/data/reporting/releases/20150202181737/data/storyboards.csv"

sql = "COPY storyboards (id, name, category, service_line, account_id, account_name, account_salesforce_id, banner_image) FROM \'#{path}\' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Here is the error message:

```
COPY storyboards (id, name, category, service_line, account_id, account_name, account_salesforce_id, banner_image) FROM '/data/reporting/releases/20150202181737/data/storyboards.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
: COPY storyboards (id, name, category, service_line, account_id, account_name, account_salesforce_id, banner_image) FROM '/data/reporting/releases/20150202181737/data/storyboards.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
: COPY storyboards (id, name, category, service_line, account_id, account_name, account_salesforce_id, banner_image) FROM '/data/reporting/releases/20150202181737/data/storyboards.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

Can you recommend a solution for this issue as I'm sure I am not the only one who has tried to do this. I am hosting my app on Engineyard. Is this an Engineyard configuation issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy data from a *CSV* that's client-side to the server, then there should be no problem. You can do this (outside of *Ruby* entirely if you want, or you could shell out from within *Ruby*) using the *psql* client and its `\copy` command. Since it operates off the local file system with, you wouldn't have any issues so long as you can access the local file path.

For copying a *CSV* on the server, you have to be a *superuser*, as the error indicates.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15431792/3583500), it would appear that the *postgres* user is configured to be a *superuser* in *Engineyard*, so if you use that user, you should be fine.

This would require a separate connection from your normal app connection in *Rails*, since that would presumably not be using the *postgres* user, but whatever user you created for your app (since your app should not generally run with superuser privileges for a variety of reasons).

Unless this is part of some sort of automated workflow that *has* to be server-side, I would recommend just using *psql* from your box with `\copy`.